# Does a GroovyMock of a non-static method have a specified behaviour?

Tags: groovy, mocking, spock, non-static

I put this in my Spock test:

```
GroovyMock( File, global: true)
File.createNewFile() >> null
```

... which I realise is unorthodox/silly/curious: `createNewFile` is a non-static method.

The code involved is like this:

```
if( indexInfoFile.createNewFile() ) {
```

... it turns out from my experiements that mocking `createNewFile` like this always returns `false`, even if you try putting a block in the mock:

```
GroovyMock( File, global: true)
File.createNewFile() >> {
    log.info( 'Hello mum!')
}
```

... the log message is not printed but `createNewFile` again returns `false`.

This is actually what I wanted (i.e. to mock a `false` return from `createNewFile`).

Is this intentional, documented behaviour?

PS Caveat: from my experience/experiments today, there is no doubt that this mock method does replace all occurrences of an invocation of this method, on any `File` instance. However, it appears also to have some alarming side-effects too: for example, a directory I created in my `given` block before the 2 `GroovyMock` lines is found **NOT** to exist afterwards, still in the `given` block, when I went

```
myDirPath.toFile().exists()
```

... I assume this is because `toFile` involves an invocation of `createNewFile`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#GroovyMocks), Groovy mocks only have additional "magic" when used with Groovy classes, but I assume that you are trying to mock `java.io.File`, which is a Java JRE class. Thus, the Groovy mock will behave like a normal Spock mock. So I don't know why you want to use the Groovy mock in the first place - maybe because you want to use the `global: true` feature in order to avoid refactoring for testability in your application class.

As you do not show us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I have no way of knowing whether `indexInfoFile` can be injected into your class/method under test or if it is a dependency created inside the method. In the latter case you need to refactor, it is as simple as that. Dependencies should be injectable, period.

As for your code snippets, there are a few things wrong with them:

- Method `File.createNewFile()` returns `boolean`, so it does not make any sense to stub it to return `null`.
- When creating a mock, all methods will automatically return `false`, `null` or `0`, depending on their return type. So there is no need to stub the result for `createNewFile()` in the first place if you want it to return `false` because it already does.
- You cannot stub an instance method by trying to override it like it was a static method. It makes no sense. Please learn Spock syntax first.

Now, assuming your class under test looks like this (already prepared or refactored for dependency injection via method argument, constructor argument or setter)...

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59842227;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class FileCreator {
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  public boolean createIndexInfoFile(File indexInfoFile) throws IOException {
    if (indexInfoFile.createNewFile()) {
      System.out.println("File \"" + indexInfoFile + "\" created");
      return true;
    }
    System.out.println("File \"" + indexInfoFile + "\" NOT created");
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new FileCreator().createIndexInfoFile(
      new File("_abc_" + RANDOM.nextInt(10000) + ".txt")
    );
  }
}
```

... then you can test it like this:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59842227

import spock.lang.Specification

class FileCreatorTest extends Specification {
  def "index info file created"() {
    given:
    File file = Mock() {
      createNewFile() >> true
    }

    expect:
    new FileCreator().createIndexInfoFile(file)
  }

  def "no index info file created"() {
    given:
    File file = Mock()

    expect:
    !new FileCreator().createIndexInfoFile(file)
  }
}
```

See? There is no need for global or Groovy mocks, normal mocks will do just fine. But you need to make your code testable instead of using fancy tricks.

Comment: This `createNewFile` command, for example, occurs in the middle of a long, but logically unitary, method called `createSpecificDirectory`, which performs all sorts of checks and creates a data file in preparation for putting Lucene index inside it. To extract this particular functionality I've now created a new single-line method, `boolean createNewFile( File file ){ file.createNewFile() }` ... which I then mock, using a `Spy`.  But it seems rubbish to create a method just to do that. And `Spies`, which I use a lot, are obviously generally disreputable. I'm a TDD amateur.

Comment: Splitting of longish methods into smaller ones are called **clean code** not rubbish, it is not just for testability, also for readability and maintainability. Besides, I did not suggest to split anything, not knowing your code structure. I was talking about dependency injection. P.S.: Why did you use a spy if a mock would suffice?

Comment: You also don't need a TDD book, I myself never read one. I just read the Spock manual and practised a bit. As for default return types, they are documented [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_default_behavior_of_mock_objects). :-) Don't feel bad about not knowing something, this is a place where you can get help and I explained it to you. Just accept some criticism, please. It is about meta topics like MCVE and reading documentation, not about not having expert knowledge with a new tool.

Comment: I've now re-thought things based on your advice: I now pass the `File` to be created as a parameter of a method `tryToCreateTheIndexFile( indexInfoFile )`: so I can pass a mock as the parameter (I think this is what you mean by "injection"), and not have to use a `Spy` any more. This is also an elegant, logical, justifiable (as opposed to artificial) "spawning" of a new method as a design change.  Thanks!